# add multiple json response in html table using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in web services application.I am getting below response and saving response in result in controller.I am able to show this in table format like,Status Code,Parameters, and response.I am executing with multiple device andtrying to display response in UI.Problem is only last mac execution json response is displaying.Below the results showing in UI.Getting two mac address but displaying same values in parameter_name,status code,message,value. I need to display json response for each device execution,

```
Mac Address Parameter Name  Status Code Message  Value
5C:E3:0E      Test           200            Success  72p3434 ////same value is displaying             
10:56:11      Test            200           Success  72p3434
```

for mac 5c:E3:0E having different values but displaying lat mac(10:56:11) execution values.
When i put alert(result["response"].status) which is showing only one (200)status if i execute multiple devices.

Thanks,
Raja

```
 Json Response
   "{\"statusCode\":200,\"parameters\": 
 [{\"name\":\"Device.Description\",\"value\":\"Gateway 
Device\",\"dataType\":0,\"parameterCount\":1,\"message\":\"Success\"}]}"

     Controller
    params[:mac].each do |mac|

     //web service call for getting description for multiple devices
    end
        result_hash["response"] = {"status": response.code, 
"parameter_name": model.to_s, "body": response.body, "accesstoken": 
access_token, "response_time": response_time.to_s}
  respond_to do |format|
format.json { render :json => result }
end


 JS File

if (result["response"].status == "200") {

    var obj = JSON.parse(result["response"].body);
    var pretty = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);
    for (var i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {

    //$('#http_response').append("Mac:"+mac+"\n\nParameter Name : 
    "+result["response"].parameter_name+"\n\nResponse Time : " + 
   result["response"].response_time + " sec\n\nResponse Body : \n" + 
   pretty);
        for (var j = 0; j < obj.parameters.length; j++) {

            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + mac[i] + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + result["response"].parameter_name + "< 
        /td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + result["response"].status + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + obj.parameters[j]["message"] + "</td>")
            tr.append("<td>" + obj.parameters[j]["value"] + "</td>")
            $('#http_response').append(tr);
        }
    }




 function getParameters
  result_hash = Hash.new().merge({"response": []})
  result_hash["pa"] = false
  result_hash["tel"] = false
  result = ""

  if params[:protocol][:pa] == "true"
    result_hash["pa"] = true
    params[:mac].each do |mac|
      client = paclient.new
      @model = params[:parameter]
      if @model.to_s.first == ","
        @model = @model[1..-1]
      end
      total_params = 1
      if @model.include? (",")
        paramArray = @modle.split(/\s*,\s*/)
        p "After Conversion"
        p paramArray

        total_params = paramArray.length
      end

      puts "Total number of Params in execution = #{total_params}"

      if total_params == 1
        if mac.nil?
          flash[:notice] = "Mac cannot be nil"
          redirect_to root_path
        elsif @dataModel.nil?
          flash[:notice] = "Parameter cannot be nil"
          redirect_to root_path
        end

        response = client.get_call(mac, @model)
        redis_client = Redis.new
        access_token = redis_client["Pa:SATToken"]
        response_time = client.response_time

        # response_time = 
   Time.at(client.response_time).utc.strftime("%M:%S.%L")

        p "RESPONSE_TIME = #{response_time}"

        p "Encoding = #{response.body.encoding}"

        response.body.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")

        p response.body

        if access_token.nil?
          sat_client = SatClient.new
          response = sat_client.get_sat_token
          body = JSON.parse(response.body)
          if response.code == "200"
            access_token = body["access_token"]
            p "Storing Token in Redis"
            redis_client = Redis.new
            redis_client["Pa:SATToken"] = access_token
            return access_token
          else
            p "SAT endpoint returned #{response.code}"
            p "#{response.body}"
            raise "Retrieving SAT Token call failed"
          end
        end
        result_hash["response"] = {"status": response.code, "parameter_name": 
     @model.to_s, "body": response.body, "accesstoken": access_token, 
   "response_time": response_time.to_s}
      else
        result_hash["response"] = {"status": "520", "body": ""}
      end
    end
  elsif params[:protocol][:pil] == "true"
    result_hash["pil"] = true
    # cima_client=CimaClient.new
    #get CIMA token

    numberOfOids = 1

    @oid = params[:oid]
    #mac = params[:mac]
    params[:mac].each do |snmpmac|
      Rails.logger.debug("SNMP MAC: #{snmpmac.inspect}")

      if @oid.to_s.first == ","
        @oid = @oid[1..-1]
        oidArray = @oid.split(/\s*,\s*/)

        numberOfOids = oidArray.length

        puts "OID ARRAY LENGTH :- #{numberOfOids}"
      end

      puts "Before Initializing"
      snmp4jclient = Snmp4jClient.new

      puts "MacAddress is " + snmpmac

      # Get IP address for the device from the Devices table owned by the user.
      @user = User.find_by(name: session[:name])
      id = @user.id.to_s
      @device = device.find_by(User_id: id, est_mac_address: snmpmac)
      # @device = device.where("User_id IS #{id} AND est_mac_address IS \"# 
    {mac}\"")
      plarform_id = @device.platform_id.to_s

      if plarform_id == "1"
        ipAddress = @device.estb_ip
      elsif plarform_id == "2"
        ipAddress = @device.cm_ip
      end

      #          Get value using XRAY SNMP

      puts "Ipaddress = " + ipAddress
      response = snmp4jclient.make_SNMP_curl_req(ipAddress, @oid)

      puts "Response is #{response}"
      response_time = snmp4jclient.response_time
      # response_time = Time.at(client.response_time).utc.strftime("%M:%S.%L")
      p "RESPONSE_TIME = #{response_time}"

      if response != ""
        if valid_json?(response)
          snmp_output = JSON.parse(response)["response"]

          # snmp_output = format_response_SNMP(snmp_output)

          if response.include?("No Such Object available") || response.include? 
     ("Error in executing snmp walk") || response.include?("noSuchInstance") || 
    response.include?("physical.device.timeout")
            result_hash["response"] = {"status": "400", "body": snmp_output, 
    "response_time": response_time.to_s, "oid": @oid}
          else
            result_hash["response"] = {"status": "200", "body": snmp_output, 
"response_time": response_time.to_s, "oid": @oid}
          end
        else
          result_hash["response"] = {"status": "404", "body": response, 
 "response_time": response_time.to_s, "oid": @oid}
        end
      else
        result_hash["response"] = {"status": "404", "body": "No Response from Server", "oid": @oid}
      end
    end
   =begin
        if (!response.include?  || )
          result_hash["response"]={"status": "200", "body": 
  JSON.parse(response)["response"]}
        else
          result_hash["response"]={"status": "400", "body": 
 JSON.parse(response)["response"]}
        end
   end

  p result = JSON.generate(result_hash)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => result }
  end
rescue Exception => e
  # redirect_to root_path
  result_hash["response"] = {"status": "ERROR", "body": e.message, "response_time": "0.00"}
  result = JSON.generate(result_hash)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => result }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: what do you get from `JSON.parse(result["response"].body)`

Comment: {"parameters":[{"name":"Device.info","value":"6AC2","dataType":0,"parameterCount":1,"message":"Success"}],"statusCode":200}

Comment: and what do you get when you have more than one record? Please update your question with what you get in response for multiple records

Comment: This is for second device. {"parameters":[{"name":"Device.info","value":"7AC2","dataType":0,"parameterCount":1,"message":"Success"}],"statusCode":200}

Comment: but only last device response is adding into html table

Comment: Found an issue.Controller will save last execution json respond only.

Comment: I just answered the same. You can accept the answer so that others may also get advantage from your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like here is something wrong with your code here:

```
result_hash["response"] = {"status": response.code, 
"parameter_name": model.to_s, "body": response.body, "accesstoken": 
access_token, "response_time": response_time.to_s}
respond_to do |format|
format.json { render :json => result }
```

You are setting `result_hash` and rendering `result`. And you are assigning `result_hash["response"]` by using `=` I think what you want is `<<` which will push data to array. Let me know if above mentioned solutions doesn't work

## Update:

```
result_hash["pa"] = false
result_hash["tel"] = false
result_hash["response"] = []
result = ""
```

and replace all the lines telling `result_hash["response"] =`  with `result_hash["response"] <<`

Comment: result_hash["response"] << {"status": response.code, "parameter_name": @model.to_s, "body": response.body, "accesstoken": access_token, "response_time": response_time.to_s}

Comment: do i need to use like?

Comment: yes. If result_hash["response"] should be an array then you need to declare it first as array and then use `<<` to push data into that array

Comment: getting error Threw an exception undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Where are you declaring result_hash["response"]? I think you have not declared that yet. First write a line before the loop `result_hash = {"response": []}`

Comment: getting same error after declaration also.They already declared     result_hash = Hash.new

Comment: do i need to remove this?

Comment: You can replace that line with my code or update that line with `result_hash = Hash.new().merge({"response": []})`

Comment: again i am getting method `<<' for nil:NilClass

Comment: No Luck.Taking last execution json response only. :(

Comment: now in your JS file put `console.log(obj.parameters[j])` and see what is in the `obj.parameters[j]`

Comment: I have changed the logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076010/adding-dynamic-row-based-on-ajax-json-response-using-java-script

Comment: Posted new question.